# Change SQlite3 version used by Python 2.6 on Mac 10.6.8

Tags: python, macos, sqlite, osx-snow-leopard

I am writing a simple Python script that fetches data from a sqlite3 database. I am experiencing the following error:

```
sqlite3.DatabaseError: file is encrypted or is not a database
```

I found out that this error is caused by a version problem of sqlite3. On the Mac (10.6.8) I need to use for now the SQLite version is 3.6.12. I downloaded SQLite 3.7.16.2 and can open the database with that version. But how can I tell Python to use the non-standard SQLite version in that script?

I am using

```
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
```

Eventually I will use Ubuntu for that project but for testing purposes I need to run the script on that particular Mac configuration. 
Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to install a newer Python.  For instance, the current python.org Python 2.7.4 installers (available [here](http://www.python.org/download/)) ship with SQLite 3.7.13.

```
$ /usr/local/bin/python2.7
Python 2.7.4 (v2.7.4:026ee0057e2d, Apr  6 2013, 11:43:10)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version_info (3, 7, 13)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to place the directory of a replacement sqlite .dyld earlier in the search path.  See `man dyld`.   This is similar to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on Linux.

Comment: This may or may not work depending on how the replacement library is built.

Comment: Thanks for this answer but that would require building sqlite3 as dyld - so I decided to download 2.7 which solves the problem too.